# .NET 6 System.Drawing.Common Runtime Switch

Tags: .net-6.0, system.drawing.common

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only System.Drawing.Common is no longer supported under on non-windows OS UNLESS a runtime configuration switch is set.  I've setup runtimeconfig.template.json and see the switch:

```
"runtimeOptions": {
      "configProperties": {
        "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true
      }
    }
```

inside the file .runtimeconfig.json in bin/Debug/net6.0

However when I run the app in a linux box using `dotnet exec app.dll` I still get PlatformNotSupportedException

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following worked for me.

Adding the following line to the .csproj file in a `PropertyGroup` section:

```
<GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
```

Next create a file named runtimeconfig.template.json in the same directory as your project file containing:

```
{
      "configProperties": {
         "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true
      }
}
```

I used the `dotnet publish` command, which created a [YourAppNameHere].runtimeconfig.json file in the output directory I supplied to  the `dotnet publish` command.

For my asp.net project, the publish resulted in the following [YourAppNameHere].runtimeconfig.jsonfile:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net6.0",
    "includedFrameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.1"
      }
    ],
    "configProperties": {
      "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true,
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataUpdater.IsSupported": false,
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false
    }
  }
}
```

This worked, where trying to follow the documentation on the page linked to in the question did not.  I think this is because I was adding the `runtimeOptions` section in the runtimeconfig.template.json file, but the `dotnet publish` command was also adding a section named `runtimeOptions`, which seems to have prevented the runtime from seeing the `System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport` option.

For this reason, I excluded the `runTimeOptions` section in my runtimeconfig.template.json file as the publish resulted in the following file that did not work:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net6.0",
    "includedFrameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.1"
      }
    ],
    "runtimeOptions": {
      "configProperties": {
        "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true
      }
    },
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataUpdater.IsSupported": false,
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false
    }
  }
}
```

Note the nested `runtimeOptions`, which I believe was causing it to fail when trying to follow the documentation in the link from the question.

Comment: The nested "runtimeOptions" was the issue.

Comment: This sucks, I've been using .net core since the DNX era and everytime there's a new update they make some shitty breaking changes that require a shitty addition to csproj and other stuff to make what was working work again, this is absolutely frustrating. And this one is also absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: This works in .Net Core 3.1 as well. I had to update System.Drawing.Common to version 6 for another reason and wasn't sure if this would work since it doesn't have a `runtimeconfig.json` file, but if you create one it will work.

Comment: This somehow does not work for me on ARM64. I am getting a proper `myapp.runtimeconfig.json` but still getting `PlatformNotSupportedException`

Answer (score 2):

One more way is to use set switch in the code:

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport", true);
```

Comment: It does not work for me on ARM64 either..

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working on Linux by downgrading System.Drawing.Common to 6.0.0
The answers listed above do not work for System.Drawing.Common 7.0.0 and above on .NET 6.

Comment: @Yunnosch accepted.