# how to reduce the size of the image in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

Here this is my code

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
await responseStream.CopyToAsync(stream);

stream.Position = 0;
var Result = stream;
byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
string Base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

// get the size of the image
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
Bitmap resizedImage = new(returnImage, new Size(310, 212));
                                              resizedImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

VisaItineraryResponse.Pax.ElementAt(paxindex)
                         .Docs.ElementAt(DocIndex).Base64String = Convert.ToString(resizedImage);
```

I got an exception while using this code

> System.Exception: Failed
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception.
> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Drawing.Common is not supported on non-Windows platforms. See https://aka.ms/systemdrawingnonwindows for more information.

Comment: In short, you need to use a different API or library. I personally have used SixLabours.ImageSharp and was fairly satisfied with the results.

Comment: If you want to use System.Drawing on non-windows platforms, you'll need this configuration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70310747/net-6-system-drawing-common-runtime-switch

Comment: @StefanFFM that doesn't work. It's only a stop-gap measure until you can migrate legacy code to other libraries. `System.Drawing` is a thin layer over GDI+, a Windows API and is really only meant to draw to the screen. It does offer some limited image manipulation support but that's it. To get it to work on Linux you'd have to emulate the entire GDI+ API, most of which is simply meaningless in web or console applications

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the provided link in the exception, it says

> Because System.Drawing.Common was designed to be a thin wrapper over Windows technologies, its cross-platform implementation is subpar.
>
> Recommended action
>
> To use these APIs for cross-platform apps, migrate to one of the following libraries:
>
> - [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp)
> - [Microsoft.Maui.Graphics](https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics)

I have used skiasharp and would recommend it. I can't say how that compares to maui graphics.

Comment: Maui.Graphis is experimental. The other option is ImageSharp, which was removed from the link because it has a dual license